# Einstein's box center of mass (thought experiment)

Tags: special-relativity

In *French, Special Relativity, pg. 16-17*, the 'Einstein's box' thought experiment is explained. It starts with a box of length $L$, mass $M$ and we emit photons from one end that have energy $E$. Then it's argued that the box moves opposite to the direction of the photons by an amount $\Delta x = \frac{E L}{M c^2}$. And then, since we suppose it's an isolated system, we say that the center of mass hasn't moved and argue that the photons must have carried some mass $m$ with them. My problem is that I can't make sense of the calculation for this center of mass. Here's the picture from the book.

[image]

We fix the origin at the left end of the box. At (a) the center of mass is in $L/2$. In (b) we have the box of mass $M-m$ that is centered at $L/2 -\Delta x$ and the photons of mass $m$ that have reached $L-\Delta x$. So the center of mass in (b) will be in

$$ (M-m) (L/2-\Delta x)+m(L-\Delta x)$$

all over the total mass $M$. Equating this with the center of mass in (a) gives $$m = \frac{2 M \Delta x}{L}$$
which is a factor of two off the correct result. Where am I wrong?

Comment: In a, the COM of the box $M$ is at $L/2$. The COM of the box plus mass $m$ is somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @mmesser314 points out, you've made a little mistake in your setup.  You say that

> We fix the origin at the left end of the box.  At (a) the center of mass is in $L/2$.

But then, this second sentence would only be true if the center-of-mass for the box without the photons $(M-m)$ were at $L/2$ *and* the photons were at the center of the box, $L/2$.  That is, if the photons only had to travel *half* as far as you actually intend for them to travel.  Not coincidentally, the value for $\Delta x$ that you've calculated is only *half* as much as the expected result.

If, instead, the photons are at $0$ initially, then the actual center of mass at (a) is
\begin{equation}
  \frac{M-m}{M}\frac{L}{2} + \frac{m}{M}\, 0 = \frac{M-m}{M}\frac{L}{2}.
\end{equation}
Now, equate *this* to your result for (b), and it works out to the same thing as French got:
\begin{equation}
  \frac{M-m}{M}\frac{L}{2} = \frac{M-m}{M} \left( \frac{L}{2} - \Delta x \right) + \frac{m}{M} \left( L - \Delta x \right).
\end{equation}
This simplifies to
\begin{equation}
  \Delta x = \frac{m L}{M} = \frac{E L}{M c^2},
\end{equation}
as expected.

It's worth noting that French's derivation was in terms of momenta and speeds, so it's very good of you to try to derive the result in a different way.  Nice work!